# Does spark process large file in the single worker

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

1. When processing a large file with Apache Spark, with, say, `sc.textFile("somefile.xml")`, does it split it for parallel processing across executors or, will it be processed as a single chunk in a single executor?
2. When using dataframes, with `implicit XMLContext` from Databricks is there any optimization pre-built for such large dataset processing?

Comment: This question has some valid answers, like, splittable files can be processed in parallel, compressed files except bzip cannot be processed in parallel, etc, yet Mr.Know-it-all * 2, choose to mark it down

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends on a file. If file format is splitable and file is bigger than configured split size it will be processed on multiple executors.
2. XML source doesn't parse full XML. it just identifies row tags as configured in `rowTag`.